# Inline code font size in header is incorrect

Tags: bug, design

Take the example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819921/how-to-embed-svg-in-html/28820415#28820415.

There's a rule somewhere that dictates that `code` elements have a font-size of 13px, regardless of the element they're in. Can this be changed to a relative size (like `em`?)

The problem exists here on meta as well.

## Example `oops`

Comment: It's **** Ugly with Courier, but what is the exact font cascade for `<code>`? (I'd happily see Courier move all the way to the end, as a matter of fact. Menlo, Andale Mono, Consolas, Lucida Sans Console; all are way, way prettier, and almost as ubiquitous.)